# Fastest Route in HYRULE HOTFOOT minigame

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I was thinking about the fastest way to reach Rossos House in the minigame HYRULE HOTFOOT. Does anyone has a good route to reach the goal WITH Pegasus boots and WITHOUT Pegasus boots?

Comment: I don't think you can win that minigame without the Pegasus boots.

Comment: I think it's possible because when you talk for the first time to the NPC (Without having Pegasus Boots!) who starts the minigame (German Version) he says that you could win the race with your "standard boots"..

Comment: You can win the first round without Pegasus Boots (only just), but not the second - the time limit is too strict. You don't get anything special for completing Round 1 without the Pegasus Boots, though.

Comment: I found this to be helpful, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meqavpzDC_4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From GameFaqs.com:

> A good alternate route requires that you have access to Lorule, and
>   have activated the "Skull Woods" weather vane. Start the race, then
>   use the fissure portal nearby to reach Lorule. Use Irene's Bell and
>   get to Skull Woods, then go south to exit the forest. Continue south,
>   east, and north to the ruined Miner's House, using the fissure portal
>   behind the bars. Then, exit the house and talk to the other Racing Bro
>   to finish the race. It should get you there with a good time,
>   especially if you have not mastered the normal path.

As to your question about doing it without the boots, I have tried and tried and I do not think it is possible; even using the method with the boots I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The other answerers are wrong. You can win BOTH rounds without the boots, easily, if you use the Lorule/Skull Woods method. It takes approximately 58 to 64 seconds, as long as you do not waste time on any enemies and are fast with the bell (also skip the broom dialogue). Having the sword fully charged can help, for cutting the purple flowers while you're walking.